# Yii framework: Controller url & parameters

Tags: php, yii

In my application I have `"PController"` with default action `"actionIndex"`, so in Yii the path becomes `p` OR `p/index`. Now in order to get certain users info I use the following path p/index?u=test where test is the username and u part of the path is basically a GET parameter (p/index?u=test).

Is there any way to do the same thing without index?u= part of the path, i.e. I want my path to look like `example.com/p/test` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application config find section for components and add options for urlManager

```
array(
    ......
    'components' => array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'rules' => array(
                '/p/<u:\w+>'=>'p/index'
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url